# How can I get the textfield's text into my view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a view controller with a table. This table loads custom cells.

In each of my custom cell, there is a textfield. The table has 3 cells. Each cell saves different values: name, birthday, address.

I want to be able to get all the values from the 3 textfields to my view controller through an IBAction. How can I save it properly and efficiently?

Comment: give the textfields tag number and get the text accordingly

Comment: add some code related to problem

Answer (score 1):

If your table is always the same, why not just create a table with static cells, and create outlets for each field?  This, to me, feels cleaner than using tags or looking for children of table cells found via their indices.

You noted that you have a UIViewController with a UITableView inside it, if I understood correctly.  If you want static cells in your nested table, you would have to embed a UITableViewController in a container inside your parent view controller.

Comment: This would only be the cleanest solution if the parent view controller was a table view controller, which would eliminating the need for embedding. Embedding view controllers inside other view controllers is rarely considered a clean solution.

Comment: I believe this article brings to light a different, yet valid, point on this subject.  Perhaps you would enjoy a light read:
http://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/containment-view-controller/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting delegates for cells to the viewcontroller, when the textfield editing ends fire it with the text you want to send.

Answer (score -1):

From anywhere within your view controller:

```
    UITableViewCell *c1 = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    NSString *name = [(UITextField *)[c1 viewWithTag:kTextFieldTag] text];
```